# Cannot read registry key when using SRVANY

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry, srvany

I am working on a script which needs to read and write a certain value to the HKLM registry hive. While it works fine when running as a script, registry access is denied when I am running the same code as a service using SRVANY utility. The service created using SRVANY runs under the Local System context which I belive should have full access to the HKLM registry hive. When running the code as a script, it is running under an administrator account.

```
REG_KEY_PATH = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\AppName\ServiceConfig"
strFilename = objWshShell.RegRead(REG_KEY_PATH)
```

The error that I get for the above code is

> Invalid root in registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\AppName\ServiceConfig"

Comment: SRVANY is very old, it will run the 32-bit version of the script interpreter.  Which cause your script to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\AppName\ServiceConfig.  Kaboom.  Guessing without you posting the command line: start c:\windows\sysnative\cscript.exe instead.

Comment: Thank you for a push in the right direction! I had read about registry redirection, but I did not realize even cscript had a 64-bit version. I was almost certain this would make it work, but I get the same error from both "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe" and "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe".

Comment: Can you read _any_ HKLM keys? Try something like `HKLM\SYSTEM\RNG\Seed`, which shouldn't be 32/64-bit dependent.

Comment: @HansPassant It works! I just changed it to c:\windows\sysnative\cscript.exe. Did not know that sysnative is not really an actual folder. Thank you so much for your help! EDIT: Not sure how I can mark your comment as the answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to use "c:\windows\sysnative\cscript.exe" to launch cscript via srvany. Full credit to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for the answer.